# Should something be done to consolidate JavaScript caching question answers?

Tags: discussion

I've a problem with JavaScript caching.  It's not a NEW problem, in any sense.  I found the following questions that all reference it:

[How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

[How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

[Clear the cache in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

[Dynamically reload local Javascript source / json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079631/dynamically-reload-local-javascript-source-json-data)

The questions are slightly different, as are the answers, but the general knowledge base becomes fairly complicated to sort out, regardless.

I assume that there's a meta-meta to this question, in that this particular information would probably be better served with a mediated wiki of some kind, Stack Overflow is in a good place to provide it, and so on.

How does consolidation of all that information work?

Comment: It **is** consolidated, in the Stack Overflow repository. You apparently had no trouble finding all these, hurray the system works.

Comment: That's pretty mediocre 'consolidation.'

Comment: Are you asking to create a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonical)?

Comment: Actually, yes, a canonical answer would have helped quite a bit.  I'm not sure which to pick; one of them is terribly outdated.

Comment: We have canonical questions, not canonical answers, I think.

Comment: And _picking_ the right one is something only you can do. The system can't simply tell you which one is the best for your use-case.

Comment: Note that rene said *create* one. It may be possible that an existing one can work with a bit of editing, but probably the chance is greater that a new one will need to be created that indeed does cover all the bases. Or don't, and be satisfied with the fact you found the information in among 15.5 million+ other questions. Mediocre consolidation does not imply there is a problem that needs solving.

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I didn't find the information at all.  We migrated to a completely different framework and one of the primary selling points was it was more modern / likely to not have the same problems.